# What does this batch code exactly do?

Tags: batch-file, colors, console

I just surfed internet to find a function in batch, which colorizes the text. This is the code:

```
:Color
:: v20 deprecated.
:: Arguments: hexColor text [\n]
:: Supported in windows XP, 7, 8.
:: In XP extended ascii characters are printed as dots.
:: For print quotes, use empty text.
SetLocal enableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Text=%~2"
If Not Defined Text (Set Text=^")
Subst `: "!Temp!" >Nul &`: &Cd \
If Not Exist `.7 (
Echo(|(Pause >Nul &Findstr "^" >`)
Set /P "=." >>` <Nul
For /F "delims=;" %%# In (
'"Prompt $H;&For %%_ In (_) Do Rem"') Do (
Set /P "=%%#%%#%%#" <Nul >`.3
Set /P "=%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#" <Nul >`.5
Set /P "=%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#" <Nul >`.7))
Set /P "LF=" <` &Set "LF=!LF:~0,1!"
For %%# in ("!LF!") Do For %%_ In (
\ / :) Do Set "Text=!Text:%%_=%%~#%%_%%~#!"
For /F delims^=^ eol^= %%# in ("!Text!") Do (
If #==#! SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
If \==%%# (Findstr /A:%~1 . \` Nul
Type `.3) Else If /==%%# (Findstr /A:%~1 . /.\` Nul
Type `.5) Else (Echo %%#\..\`>`.dat
Findstr /F:`.dat /A:%~1 .
Type `.7))
If "\n"=="%~3" (Echo()
Goto :Eof
```

Can anyone please explain how is this working? I would really want to know what does each phrase do and how it participates in printing out color text.

P.S. I know most of the stuff what's happening there, I just don't know how it makes the console print out text in color and why does it create files in %Temp% directory.

I would like for the explanation to be step by step and easy to understand please.

Thank you!

Comment: `findstr /a` is the actual command that colorizes the output, everything else is preparing a file for it. The code is intentionally cryptic because obviously the author enjoys this code "style" so it might be much more fun for you to decypher it yourself by simply reformatting it in a human-readable fashion with proper indents and then reading the help on `prompt` and `findstr`. BTW there's a [newer version 23](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=41155#p41155) on dostips.

Comment: Thanks I would give you +1 if you posted it as answer. P.S. I know there's a new version, but it's slower so I don't use it.

Comment: I thought (and still think) someone else might give an actual expanded answer you were hoping for...

Comment: I know, I just said I would still give you +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is going on but the easiest way for me is with powershell:

Put this at the top after `@echo off`

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
set "DEL=%%a"
)
rem Prepare a file "X" with only one dot
<nul > X set /p ".=."
```

(It will create a file "x" that will stick around. Anoying but nothing much.

Then put this at the complete bottom of the script.

```
:colorEcho
set "param=^%~2" !
set "param=!param:"=\"!"
findstr /p /A:%1 "." "!param!\..\X" nul
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
exit /b
```

Then use this format to make colored text:

```
call :ColorEcho 81 "text" &echo.
```

the `81` is the color code for cmd. In the command prompt run `color /?` and you'll find the color codes there. The first one is the background the second is the text.